# unresolved external symbol repeat but please assist

Tags: c++

I've read up on unresolved external symbol errors for the past 1 hr + and tried fixing my error but I think it's time for me to have a fresh set of eyes look at this.

I'm building a trading program in QT using an API from Interactivebrokers.com.

The API has a virtual class `EWrapper` which I have inherited from with a class `EWrapperSubclass`

In my `EWrapperSubclass.cpp` I have defined everything with the required `EWrapperSubclass::Method` syntax to ensure that the `Method` is referring to that class' method.

In my IBProject.cpp I have a simple `EWrapper` variable that points to a `new EWrapperSubclass`. That is where the unresolved external symbol error occurs. I get the error:

`LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl EWrapperSubclass::EWrapperSubclass(void)" (??0EWrapperSubclass@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: __cdecl IBProject::IBProject(class QWidget *)" (??0IBProject@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z)`

Can someone please be so kind as to tell me what I a may be doing wrong?

EWrapperSubclass.h

```
#ifndef EWRAPPERSUBCLASS_H
#define EWRAPPERSUBCLASS_H
#include "Shared/EWrapper.h"
class EClientSocket;
class EWrapperSubclass : public EWrapper
{
public:
    EWrapperSubclass();
    ~EWrapperSubclass();
    EClientSocket *pEClientSocket;

    ...//various methods declared here with void methodname
 }
```

EWrapperSubclass.cpp

```
#include "Shared/EWrapper.h"
#include "ewrappersubclass.h"
#include "SocketClient/src/EClientSocket.h"

EWrapperSubclass::EWrapperSubclass()
{
    pEClientSocket = new EClientSocket(this);
    pEClientSocket->eConnect("127.0.0.1",4001,0);
    connect(this,SIGNAL(disconnected()),this,SLOT(reconnect());
}

EWrapperSubclass::~EWrapperSubclass(){
    pEClientSocket->eDisconnect();
    delete pEClientSocket;
}

void EWrapperSubclass::isConnected(){
    return pEClientSocket->isConnected();
}

...//various methods defined here as void EWrapperSubclass::Methodname
```

IBProject.h

```
#ifndef IBPROJECT_H
#define IBPROJECT_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "Shared/EWrapper.h"
#include "ewrappersubclass.h"


namespace Ui {
    class IBProject;
}

class EWrapper;
class EWrapperSubclass;
class IBProject : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit IBProject(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~IBProject();

private:
    Ui::IBProject *ui;
    EWrapper *pewrapper;
};

#endif // IBPROJECT_H
```

IBproject.cpp

```
#include "ibproject.h"
#include "ui_ibproject.h"

IBProject::IBProject(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::IBProject)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    pewrapper = new EWrapperSubclass;

    connect(ui->tradeButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(on_tradeButton_clicked()));
    connect(pewrapper,SIGNAL(connected()),this,SLOT(on_connected));
    connect(pewrapper,SIGNAL(disconnected()),this,SLOT(on_disconnected));
}

IBProject::~IBProject()
{
    delete ui;
    delete pewrapper;
}
```

Comment: And the file `EWrapperSubclass.cpp` is properly compiled and linked with the rest of the project?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Just what I was thinking... Chowza: How do you handle project dependencies in Microsoft Visual C++?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I would think so, how can I check for sure? (I am developing in QT ide)

Comment: @Chowza: You use Visual C++, right? If you can tell us how you handle project dependencies, then you'll know for sure. Otherwise, this is most likely your error. ["Project dependencies in Microsoft Visual Studio"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et61xzb3(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: @cf16 correct. undefinedbehaviour, in my QT .pro file I have sources += EWrapperSubclass.cpp so it should be included in the project

Comment: have you implemented all virtual functions, even with empty body? I remember I had similar issue on windows, but leave it unresolved

Comment: @cf16 yup I double checked that a few times. Also I would get an abstract base class error if that was the issue

Comment: this has to work, no other option, so must be the issue with library

Comment: @cf16 Are you saying that the TWS API Library provided by IB has an error and my code is correct? If so why has so many people been able to make trading programs in IB?

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour I use the QT IDE

Comment: no I say you did something wrong. First thing, look at TestPosixClientSocket, I will give an example

Answer (score 0):

PosixTestClient.h

```
#ifndef posixtestclient_h__INCLUDED
#define posixtestclient_h__INCLUDED

#include "EWrapper.h"

#include <memory>
#include <stdio.h> //printf()

namespace IB {

class EPosixClientSocket;

enum State {
    ST_CONNECT,
    ST_PLACEORDER,
    ST_PLACEORDER_ACK,
    ST_CANCELORDER,
    ST_CANCELORDER_ACK,
    ST_PING,
    ST_PING_ACK,
    ST_IDLE
};


class PosixTestClient : public EWrapper
{
public:

    PosixTestClient();
    ~PosixTestClient();

    void processMessages();

public:

    bool connect(const char * host, unsigned int port, int clientId = 0);
    void disconnect() const;
    bool isConnected() const;

private:

    void reqCurrentTime();
    void placeOrder();
    void cancelOrder();

public:
    // events
    void tickPrice(TickerId tickerId, TickType field, double price, int canAutoExecute);
    void tickSize(TickerId tickerId, TickType field, int size);
    void tickOptionComputation( TickerId tickerId, TickType tickType, double impliedVol, double delta,
        double optPrice, double pvDividend, double gamma, double vega, double theta, double undPrice);
    void tickGeneric(TickerId tickerId, TickType tickType, double value);
    void tickString(TickerId tickerId, TickType tickType, const IBString& value);
//... etc

private:

    std::auto_ptr<EPosixClientSocket> m_pClient;
    State m_state;
    time_t m_sleepDeadline;

    OrderId m_orderId;
};
```

}

Implementation, PosixTestClient.cpp

```
#include "PosixTestClient.h"

#include "EPosixClientSocket.h"
/* In this example we just include the platform header to have select(). In real
   life you should include the needed headers from your system. */
#include "EPosixClientSocketPlatform.h"

#include "Contract.h"
#include "Order.h"

#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#if defined __INTEL_COMPILER
# pragma warning (disable:869)
#elif defined __GNUC__
# pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wswitch"
# pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-parameter"
#endif  /* __INTEL_COMPILER */

namespace IB {

const int PING_DEADLINE = 2; // seconds
const int SLEEP_BETWEEN_PINGS = 30; // seconds

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// member funcs
PosixTestClient::PosixTestClient()
    : m_pClient(new EPosixClientSocket(this))
    , m_state(ST_CONNECT)
    , m_sleepDeadline(0)
    , m_orderId(0)
{
}

PosixTestClient::~PosixTestClient()
{
}

bool PosixTestClient::connect(const char *host, unsigned int port, int clientId)
{
    // trying to connect
    printf( "Connecting to %s:%u clientId:%d\n", !( host && *host) ? "127.0.0.1" : host, port, clientId);

    bool bRes = m_pClient->eConnect2( host, port, clientId);

    if (bRes) {
        printf( "Connected to %s:%u clientId:%d\n", !( host && *host) ? "127.0.0.1" : host, port, clientId);
    }
    else
        printf( "Cannot connect to %s:%u clientId:%d\n", !( host && *host) ? "127.0.0.1" : host, port, clientId);

    return bRes;
}

void PosixTestClient::disconnect() const
{
    m_pClient->eDisconnect();

    printf ( "Disconnected\n");
}

bool PosixTestClient::isConnected() const
{
    return m_pClient->isConnected();
}

void PosixTestClient::processMessages()
{
//...
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// methods
void PosixTestClient::reqCurrentTime()
{
    printf( "--> Requesting Current Time2\n");

    // set ping deadline to "now + n seconds"
    m_sleepDeadline = time( NULL) + PING_DEADLINE;

    m_state = ST_PING_ACK;

    m_pClient->reqCurrentTime();
}

//...etc

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// events
void PosixTestClient::orderStatus( OrderId orderId, const IBString &status, int filled,
       int remaining, double avgFillPrice, int permId, int parentId,
       double lastFillPrice, int clientId, const IBString& whyHeld)

{}

void PosixTestClient::error(const int id, const int errorCode, const IBString errorString)
{
    printf( "Error id=%d, errorCode=%d, msg=%s\n", id, errorCode, errorString.c_str());

    if( id == -1 && errorCode == 1100) // if "Connectivity between IB and TWS has been lost"
        disconnect();
}

void PosixTestClient::tickPrice( TickerId tickerId, TickType field, double price, int canAutoExecute) {}
void PosixTestClient::tickSize( TickerId tickerId, TickType field, int size) {}
void PosixTestClient::tickOptionComputation( TickerId tickerId, TickType tickType, double impliedVol, double delta,
                                             double optPrice, double pvDividend,
                                             double gamma, double vega, double theta, double undPrice) {}
void PosixTestClient::tickGeneric(TickerId tickerId, TickType tickType, double value) {}
void PosixTestClient::tickString(TickerId tickerId, TickType tickType, const IBString& value) {}
void PosixTestClient::tickEFP(TickerId tickerId, TickType tickType, double basisPoints, const IBString& formattedBasisPoints,
                               double totalDividends, int holdDays, const IBString& futureExpiry, double dividendImpact, double dividendsToExpiry) {}
void PosixTestClient::openOrder( OrderId orderId, const Contract&, const Order&, const OrderState& ostate) {}
void PosixTestClient::openOrderEnd() {}
void PosixTestClient::winError( const IBString &str, int lastError) {}
void PosixTestClient::connectionClosed() {}
void PosixTestClient::updateAccountValue(const IBString& key, const IBString& val,
                                          const IBString& currency, const IBString& accountName) {}
void PosixTestClient::updatePortfolio(const Contract& contract, int position,
        double marketPrice, double marketValue, double averageCost,
        double unrealizedPNL, double realizedPNL, const IBString& accountName){}
void PosixTestClient::updateAccountTime(const IBString& timeStamp) {}
void PosixTestClient::accountDownloadEnd(const IBString& accountName) {}
void PosixTestClient::contractDetails( int reqId, const ContractDetails& contractDetails) {}
void PosixTestClient::bondContractDetails( int reqId, const ContractDetails& contractDetails) {}
void PosixTestClient::contractDetailsEnd( int reqId) {}
void PosixTestClient::execDetails( int reqId, const Contract& contract, const Execution& execution) {}
void PosixTestClient::execDetailsEnd( int reqId) {}

void PosixTestClient::updateMktDepth(TickerId id, int position, int operation, int side,
                                      double price, int size) {}
void PosixTestClient::updateMktDepthL2(TickerId id, int position, IBString marketMaker, int operation,
                                        int side, double price, int size) {}
void PosixTestClient::updateNewsBulletin(int msgId, int msgType, const IBString& newsMessage, const IBString& originExch) {}
void PosixTestClient::managedAccounts( const IBString& accountsList) {}
void PosixTestClient::receiveFA(faDataType pFaDataType, const IBString& cxml) {}
void PosixTestClient::historicalData(TickerId reqId, const IBString& date, double open, double high,
                                      double low, double close, int volume, int barCount, double WAP, int hasGaps) {}
void PosixTestClient::scannerParameters(const IBString &xml) {}
void PosixTestClient::scannerData(int reqId, int rank, const ContractDetails &contractDetails,
       const IBString &distance, const IBString &benchmark, const IBString &projection,
       const IBString &legsStr) {}
void PosixTestClient::scannerDataEnd(int reqId) {}
void PosixTestClient::realtimeBar(TickerId reqId, long time, double open, double high, double low, double close,
                                   long volume, double wap, int count) {}
void PosixTestClient::fundamentalData(TickerId reqId, const IBString& data) {}
void PosixTestClient::deltaNeutralValidation(int reqId, const UnderComp& underComp) {}
void PosixTestClient::tickSnapshotEnd(int reqId) {}
void PosixTestClient::marketDataType(TickerId reqId, int marketDataType) {}

}
```

and use this in main:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
# include <windows.h>
# define sleep( seconds) Sleep( seconds * 1000);
#else
# include <unistd.h>
#endif

#include "PosixTestClient.h"

const unsigned MAX_ATTEMPTS = 1;
const unsigned SLEEP_TIME = 10;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    IB::PosixTestClient client;
        client.connect( host, port, clientId);
        //...
}
```